# Sending emails to workers at a company where I just applied?

Tags: applications

I recently applied for a job. After I applied, a small dialog box popped up on the companies website that said something like 'message the workers in this company, and try making your chance to get the job higher'. So should I send LinkedIn messages to the people who work at this company?  What would I say in the message?

> "Hello, I recently applied for this position, and I'm very interested,
>   here is my portfolio."

Comment: never heard of anything like that before, are you sure it's a legitimate company and website?

Comment: Adding on to @Kilisi comment: and if it is legitimate, are you sure you want to work at a company that hires like that?

Comment: Did the dialog box have a space for you to write a message? Or a link? Or did it just say to go to LinkedIn? And this was on the actual company website, not a 3rd party recruiter? For what it's worth I agree I've never seem that either and it sounds very dubious -- although I guess it could be a country-specific thing.

Comment: Were you applying directly on the company's page. Or was it a third party site listing lots of other jobs as well?

Comment: I just edited the title to be a little more specific about your question. If you feel I have misrepresented your question, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: It really does depend if was on the companies official application page, or some 3rd part one. If a 3rd party one, its almost certainly a scam or some kind of LinkedIn spam.
If on real site,  what kind of note would they expect you to CC to entire company?  Unless it is just a messed way of asking for a cover letter.

Comment: It sounds like they might be using a third party web site. That's the only explanation that sounds sensible to me.

Answer (score 3):

A web form that scrapes all of the employees of a company and sends a message to them? **I cannot imagine any context where receiving a random message from a random applicant would cause me to have a more favorable opinion of that person.** And if everyone at the company got the same message at the same time, it would actually lower your chances because you would be remembered as "the spammer," if anyone remembers you at all.

It is far more professional to identify specific people at the company who are involved in making the hiring decisions, and send them a cover letter-like message (assuming the application form didn't already contain a place for a cover letter-like message).

It would also be appropriate to find a phone number for the application processor at the company and call him/her a few days after posting the application to ensure they got it and inquire on its status.

Just remember, there's a line somewhere between being proactive and being a pest. A blast email to everyone at the company is way over that line.

Comment: I would imagine him getting a pop up to send emails to everyone is something baked into the website and anyone applying would have equal chances of blasting everyone a email. As such, I think employees are expecting it and would probably discard the message than form an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is very rare. Or, at least, I haven't seen anything like this before.

However, as you say it happened, then make sure that the dialog box is not asking about your personal details like Name, e-mail id, etc.

If not, then go ahead and post the message.

Otherwise, **close the dialog box**. It's better to message them on LinkedIn or through a separate mail, rather than trusting a dialog box and possible compromise of privacy.

And when HR asks so, be honest and tell him/her that you were concerned about your privacy and thus, did not move ahead with it. They should understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the full context of the application. Is it a form which you simply submitted a résumé? In that case this may be your opportunity to submit your cover letter, instead of sending an email some other way.

If you *don't* have a cover letter, you may wish to invest time in writing one. Résumés can only go so far and cannot highlight things nearly so well as documents which are written in actual English (most advice on writing résumés actually suggest a bizarre not-quite-grammatical approach).